# VS2017: Compilation does not copy and deletes Result Files

Tags: visual-studio, build, compilation, msbuild

My application uses some third party libraries and data files.
To place third party files in the results folder at compile time, I use this setting in the c # project file:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
  <Content Include="..\..\ThirdParty\SQLite\3.27.2\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" Link="ThirdParty\SQLite\3.27.2\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll" />
  <Content Include="..\..\ThirdParty\SQLite\3.27.2\x86\System.Data.SQLite.dll" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" Link="ThirdParty\SQLite\3.27.2\x86\System.Data.SQLite.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

That third party files must be copied while **Preserving the newest** to the result destination folder.

When the compilation is clean (**Clean then Build** or **Rebuild**) for the first time all is generated and copied correctly, the application runs correctly by running it from visual studio by pressing the Start/Play button.

So when closing the application or stop from visual studio then **Start again the previus files copied correctly seem deleted**.

Then if I clean and recompile the solution all the files are copied correctly to the destination folder.

More Info:

- It happens too when generating both Result and Debug, in x86 and also in x64.
- Windows 10 x64; Visual Studio Community 2017 v15.19.20; MSBuild.
- The same happened with Visual Studio Professional 2015 Update 3.
- Apparently it is not the error of dependencies from other dependencies because in the clean compilation the files are copied correctly.

Comment: What do you mean `then in consecutive executions or following compilations the files copied "preserving the new ones" seem deleted.`? Could you please give us some more explaination with a example or give us some screenshots? And what is the properties of those content files?

Comment: Make a detailed log file, with verbosity set to detailed. Look for the copy action (or lack thereof) of the content files. Without any code to show us, we will be of limited use here.

Comment: What I want to say is that my solution is composed of about 20 C # projects.
Some projects have files in third-party folder structures, some of them are DLL libraries, others are simply common resource files, these files are configured as "Content", and copy to the result directory preserving the most recent. that is, if the destination file is more recent then they should not be replaced in the result directory.

Comment: After several executions from the VS, or debugging sessions, I discover that I get the exception "FileNotFoundException" when I load some of those files. and is that not only were they not copied, but they were eliminated from the results directory.

Comment: You should really show us a minimal example that explains your problems, otherwise its just taking your word is feeble. Without any build log, reproduce steps, screenshots, you could not get any useful info but only endless question.    To improve your chances of getting an answer, I suggest you can check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Well I keep trying to find the problem, what I can verify is that if I execute "recompile solution" twice in a row the files are finally copied, I think there could be some problem with the compilation order.